# Zune API ZuneCore.dll

Tags: api, zune, wmplib

I noticed the other day that the Zune PC Software exposes a type library (ZuneCore.dll). It seems to be related to the WMPLib API in some way but I can't figure out how to use it either from VB6 or C#.

Has anybody tried this and had any luck?

Dave

Answer (score 6):

May be an old question, but this link might help: http://zunelcd.codeplex.com/ If you download the source for this project one of the class libraries is a decent API for communicating with the Zune Software.

Answer (score 1):

i just found out about this -> http://soapitstop.com/blogs/fleamarket/archive/2008/03/03/read-the-zune-collection-in-net-from-zune-s-own-api.aspx but it seems a bit outdated Initialize method now takes some parameters and i dont know what to put there!

Comment: Excellent, I'll check that out later, looks promising, thanks!

Comment: if you find out how to use it pls tell me!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a reference to it from a .NET project in Visual Studio. Perhaps this namespace will appear magically: MicrosoftZuneLibrary