# Access Pictures in Win Phone 7 using WPF

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-7

I'd like to write a WPF Windows app that can access the images on my Windows Phone.

When I plug the phone in, I don't see it. I've had other phones that showed up in Windows Explorer as another hard drive and you could copy images on/off the phone.

How can I access the images on a Windows 7 Phone in a WPF application? How can I get started? Which namespaces are most relevant?

Answer (score 2):

You can only get the images off the phone via Zune, unfortunately there is no official API for getting the pictures.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015286/zune-api-zunecore-dll) might be of help.